# Go regex string validation

Tags: regex, go

In go there is the function MatchString which can be used to match a string with a regex, however, the function returns true if a substring that matches the regex is found.

Is there a way/similar function that returns true only when the whole of the string is matched (e.g. if I have [0-9]{2} and my string is 213, the return value should be false). ? or should this be done from the regex string itself ?

Comment: updated the answer a bit, you can try now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[0-9]{2}$
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/9Qa071/6)

GO CODE:

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^[0-9]{2}$`)
    var str = `213`

    for i, match := range re.FindAllString(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match, "found at index", i)
    }
}
```

[Run the code here](http://ideone.com/HuD8Ne)